# getting play.api.Configuration conflict in apploader

Tags: playframework-2.6

I am getting the following error in my Apploader. I don't know from where `ConfigurationComponents` is getting included in my code.

```
Error:(63, 7) class AppComponents inherits conflicting members:
  method configuration in class BuiltInComponentsFromContext of type => play.api.Configuration  and
  method configuration in trait ConfigurationComponents of type ()play.api.Configuration
(Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in class AppComponents.);
 other members with override errors are: environment, applicationLifecycle, httpErrorHandler, fileMimeTypes
class AppComponents (context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
```

Also, I dont understand the statement in the above error `other members with override errors are: environment, applicationLifecycle, httpErrorHandler, fileMimeTypes`

Snippet of my Apploader.scala code is

```
class AppComponents (context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
  with CassandraRepositoryComponents
  with HttpFiltersComponents
  with AssetsComponents
  with CSRFComponents { ... }
```

I also notice that the different use of `()` and `=>` in the statement `=> play.api.Configuration and method configuration in trait ConfigurationComponents of type ()play.api.Configuration`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved when I removed `import play.controllers.AssetsComponents`. It seems I included this file by mistake which caused conflicts.